# Instancia de un objeto en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from Tree import Node

q = Node(p)
```

El problema con el código es que me sale este mensaje:

> 'Node' is not callable
>   This inspection highlights attempts to call objects which are not callable, like, for example, tuples.

Esto no me deja acceder a los métodos de la clase Node

```
class Node:
   txt = 0
   izq = None
   der = None

   def __init__(self, txt):
      self.txt = txt
      self.izq = None
      self.der = None

#Setters
   def setTxt(self, ntxt):
      self.txt = ntxt

   def setIzq(self, nIzq):
      self.izq = nIzq

   def setDer(self, nDer):
      self.der = nDer

#Getters
   def getTxt(self):
      return self.txt

   def getIzq(self):
      return self.izq

   def getDer(self):
      return self.der
```

Comment: Si `Tree` es el nombre de tu módulo y su contenido es el que muestras y no reescribes `Node` en el módulo donde lo importas esto no debe pasar. Haz justo antes de la instacia (la linea donde te da el error) `print(type(Node))` a ver que te dice.

Comment: Tree on Python!
<class 'module'>
Tree on Python!
<class 'module'>

Comment: Un modulo no se puede llamar, deberia ser una clase (que con el código que presentas así es). No obstante es un poco extraño el mensaje de error, ¿en qué plataforma o IDE estas desarrollando y que librerias usas? No es un mensaje de error estándar de Python tal y como lo presentas. A ver si puedes añadir más información porque con lo que proporcionas el error no es reproducible, si el contenido de Tree.py es el que muestras al final de tu pregunta el código es correcto y su forma de usarlo sería correcta.

Comment: Intenta hacer lo siguiente a ver que te dice: `import Tree` y luego instancia con `q = Tree.Node(p)`

Comment: Tree es un paquete que contiene dos archivos llamados __init__.py y Node.py. Pero si, esa información me falto.

Comment: Raul eso explica el problema, ¿podrias actualizar la pregunta agregando la estructura de tu proyecto (al menos la localización del módulo desde donde importas con respecto al directorio `Tree`) y el contenido del  `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 3):

Por lo que comentas `Tree` es en realidad un paquete que dentro contiene un módulo llamado `Node`, que a su vez contiene una clase llamada `Node`. Algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Presuponiendo que `__init__.py` esté vacío, algunas de las formas correctas para importar desde `main.py` son:

```
from Tree import Node

q = Node.Node(p)
```

---

```
from Tree.Node import Node

q = Node(p)
```

---

```
import Tree.Node

q = Tree.Node.Node(p)
```

Personalmente prefiero nombrar al módulo con minúscula y a la clase contenida en él con mayúscula, queda más legible que es cada cosa.

Answer (score 1):

en el código que compartiste hay varias cosas para mejorar.

Por un lado, no está definida la variable 'p'. Podríamos arreglarlo de la siguiente manera.

```
from Tree import Node
p = 1 # un valor cualquiera
q = Node(p)
```

Por otro lado, hay que ver donde definiste la clase Node. Podrias empezar por definirla en el mismo archivo así ves si funciona:

```
class Node:
   def __init__(self, txt):
       self.txt = txt
       self.izq = None
       self.der = None

p = 1 # un valor cualquiera
q = Node(p)
```

En python no hace falta que definas los atributos de la clase por fuera del constructor y tampoco hacen falta los getters y setters como se definen en java. En python todos los atributos son públicos, salvo que empiezen con doble guión bajo por ej: self.__valor = x.
Lo que sí existe es un decorador que se llama property.

```
@property
def valores(self):
    return self.__valor
```

Podes mirar un poco de esto aca:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618002/python-property-versus-getters-and-setters